# install epson v39 on nixOS

Tags: scanner, nixos, sane

I'm trying to get a epson v39 scanner running under NixOS.

I followed the instructions on [this](https://nixos.org/wiki/Scanners) page, which basically tells you to add the following to the configuration.nix :

```
hardware.sane.enable = true;
# nixpkgs.config.sane.snapscanFirmware = /firmware/esfw41.bin;
nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides = pkgs: {
  xsaneGimp = xsane.override { gimpSupport = true; };
};
```

I commented out the firmware section, since I would not know where to get a "blob" like this for my scanner.

anyways. The rebuilding works. When trying `sane-find-scanner` in the command line, it looks like the scanner is detected:

```
[...]
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x013d [Epson Perfection V39]) at libusb:003:005
[...]
```

However, when trying to use `scanimage` as root, I get this for example:

```
bash-4.3# scanimage -L
[bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
```

Note: During none of the steps I see any activity on the device (lights, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I managed Epson Perfection 1270 to work like this:

1. import module mentioned in https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/17411
2. replace line `cat ${builtins.toFile "" (c.value + "\n")} >>"$f"` in that module with `cat ${builtins.toFile "" (c.value + "\n")} >"$f"`
3. add 

      `hardware.sane.enable = true;
      hardware.sane.extraConfig.snapscan = ''
        # Epson Perfection 1270
        firmware /path/to/firmware/ESFW3E.bin
        # in your case 
        # usb 0x04b8 0x013d
        usb 0x04b8 0x0120
      '';
      hardware.sane.snapshot = true;`

and that's it . Firmware is a must and was downloaded somewhere from internet.